# Can we install Android 4.4 factory image on Samsung Galaxy Core?

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-grand

Google has released Android 4.4 [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam) for Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 today. The steps to install Android 4.4 factory image in nexus 4 is

1. Download the factory image corresponding to your device's model and version
2. Extract the downloaded file and `cd` into the extracted directory.
3. run `adb reboot-bootloader`
4. run `./flash-all.sh`

Can I follow the same steps and install the above Android 4.4 in Samsung Galaxy Core or in Galaxy Grand? Any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Those ROMs are intended for those devices only. Flashing a ROM that is not compatible with the device can brick the device.

You should wait for 4.4 ROMs for your devices.

Comment: Hi @geffchang, thanks for your quick reply. Is there any other way other than to wait for the 4.4 ROM release for my device? I really want to try it in my device :)

Comment: @Ibungo You can check if there are custom ROMs for your phone that are using 4.4. If a stock 4.4 ROM is already available for your phone and is available in other countries, you could download the stock ROM from sammobile, and flash it using Odin. However, the RISK is yours (same for using custom ROMs).